Probability of i.i.d. uninform random variables assuming a particular ordering.
I'm doing the following exercise.

Let $X_0, X_1, X_2, . . . , X_k$ be uniformly and independently distributed on [0, 1]. Declare that the $j^\text{th}$ event succeeds if and only if $X_j < X_0$. Explain why the probability that $X_k < X_0$, given that $X_0$ is the smallest of the set $ \\{ X_0, X_1, X_2, . . . , X_{k-1} \\}$, should be $\frac{1}{k+1}$.

I got a different answer, but can't see where I got it wrong. Please comment on my answer below.

Let A be the event that $X_k < X_0$, and B the event that $X_0$ is the smallest in $ \\{X_0,...X_{k-1}\\}$.
Conditioned on the value $p$ of $X_0$, we have: $$P(B) = \int_0^1 P(B|p) f(p) dp = \int_0^1 (1-p)^{k-1} dp = \frac{1}{k}$$
Likewise, $$P(AB) = \int_0^1 P(AB | p) f(p) dp = \int_0^1 p (1-p)^{k-1} dp = \frac{1}{k+1}$$
So $P(A|B) = \frac{k}{k+1}$


$\int_0^1 p (1 - p)^{k - 1} = \frac{1}{k^2 + k}$
